# An inequality and random number and algorithm problem

Tags: inequality, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I've been run into a problem which is absolutely not as simple as is looking, I just don't know how to describe it.I think it is a math problem eventually?

Suppose a target number A and a mistake C given, and require a random number x, then we have

$$
\left |\frac{x-A}{A}  \right |<\pm C
$$
and then generate a x between this:
$$
(1-C)A<x<(1+C)A
$$
then I generate the next x BASED ON THE LAST NUMBER, which means 
$$
\left |\frac{x-A}{A}  \right |<\pm C , A=x_{1}
$$

OK, here comes the hardest part: The average of those x must be in the mistake given with the first A, that is
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i - A}{A}<C
$$

I don't know if I make it clear my brain is soooooo MESSEDUP now.I think you guys can get the idea right??any pointer will be grateful!!!

[here is a simple C program simplely implements the first part](http://ideone.com/Kcn0uj)

the problem is  how to control the generate rules so that the final mistake is in control.

Comment: Should that last equation not have $\frac{1}{n}$ in front of the summation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment, so assuming I deciphered the question right, you seem to want to generate $n$ "random" numbers $x_i, 1 \le i \le n$, with $x_0=A$ and $\left|\dfrac{x_{i}-x_{i-1}}{x_{i-1}} \right| < C$, s.t. $\left|\dfrac{\sum x_{i}-nA}{nA} \right| < C$.  So you need
$$x_{i-1}(1-C) < x_i < x_{i-1}(1+C) \quad \forall i \in {1, 2, ...n} \tag{1}$$
and
$$nA(1-C) < \sum x_i < nA(1+C) \tag{2}$$

Assuming further that by random you mean uniformly distributed, $(1)$ can be implemented easily, recursively. If $n$ is small, a simple solution would be to generate $n \; x_i$ satisfying $(1)$ and then reject the whole lot if $(2)$ fails.

Comment: so the gist is try again and again until it gets right?

Comment: Depending on what random distribution you use (not mentioned in Q) and how large C is, you could have a high (or low) chance of success. For eg if the distribution is symmetric and triangular, you may get good results fast.  Seems very odd to have the distribution unspecified - knowing that may simplify things. Where did you encounter the problem?

Comment: It was a ERP system of a Concrete company, needs to generate a serial of statistics that fits this problem described. I think they don't care about distribution but there may be a more elegant way to do this. That's why I'm figuring is there a algorithm or what.

Comment: If the distribution doesn't matter, you could as well just set all $x_i=A$ or something similarly very narrowly spread for instant soln. From the case you mention perhaps normal distribution should model OK, with mean the previous $x_i$ and $6\sigma$ to encompass the allowed range. Diasard any value outside this range and after n variates are generated, check the sum condition. Best of luck for any simpler algorithm.

Comment: thanks bro, it helped a lot

Comment: Glad it was of some help.